# DB Laravel get and first in same time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to show only one result from "links, tags, pages", "->first()", but, I want to show multiple results from "comments", "->get()", separate it in one array, and send to view, how can I do this?

```
    $link = DB::table('links')
            ->join('tags', 'tags.id', 'links.tag')
            ->join('pages', 'pages.id', '=', 'links.page_id')
            ->leftJoin('comments', 'comments.link_id', '=', 'links.id')
            ->select('links.photo', 'links.id', 'links.description', 'links.country', 'links.url', 'links.suggestions', 'links.shares', 'links.friendly_url', 'links.page_id', 'links.sponsored', 'links.clicks', 'links.title', 'tags.color', 'tags.id as tag_id', 'tags.name', 'pages.name as p_name', 'pages.description as p_description', 'pages.id as p_id', 'pages.followers', 'pages.links', 'pages.friendly_url as p_friendly_url', 'pages.photo as p_photo')
            ->where('links.friendly_url', $id)
            ->first();


    return view('site.link', compact('link'));
```

DD($link);

```
0 => Link {#291 ▼
      #relations: array:3 [▼
        "page" => Page {#295 ▶}
        "tag" => Tag {#289 ▶}
        "comments" => Collection {#292 ▼
          #items: array:2 [▼
            0 => Comment {#299 ▶}
            1 => Comment {#301 ▶}
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Take advantage of Eloquent and it's relationships.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Eloquent. Define relationships:

```
public function page()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Page::class);
}

public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tag::class, 'tag');
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

And do this:

```
Link::with('page', 'tag', 'comments')->where('friendly_url', $id)->first()
```

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso it's all in these relationships already. If you follow [Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions), you don't need to define foreign keys in the relationships. You can also find some examples [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Thank you so much, much easier, how can I get the authors of the comments? "COMMENTS.user_id = USERS.id".

Comment: And how can I pick which fields to get?

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso define a `belongsTo()` relationship called `user` in `Comment` and then load the data with `Link::with('page', 'tag', 'comments.user')->where...`

Comment: To select fields, use `->select()` or `addSelect()` in the [constrains](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: Thank you, I'm beginner, how I can show the comments in view? I try @foreach($link->comments() as $item, but return a stranger big array...

Comment: `$link->comments as $comment`

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), but exists a comment with link_id = 4

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso I don't see your code but it sounds like you're using `select()` without getting primary kay or foreign key.

Comment: I'm not using select yet, and all tables got "id" as primary key and auto increment... I don't understand why...

Comment: I edit the post with the result in DD, look there, the comments were obtained... What could be happening?

Comment: 0 => Link {#291 ▼
      #relations: array:3 [▼
        "page" => Page {#295 ▶}
        "tag" => Tag {#289 ▶}
        "comments" => Collection {#292 ▼
          #items: array:2 [▼
            0 => Comment {#299 ▶}
            1 => Comment {#301 ▶}
          ]
        }
      ]